# Why is my Xuggle video converter not working

Tags: java, image, video, xuggler

I hava this piece of code:

```
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;

public class ImageToVideo implements Runnable {

    private static Dimension dimension;
    private final IMediaWriter writer;
    long startTime;
    LoadFrame loadframe;

    public ImageToVideo(int framespersecond, LoadFrame loadframe) {
        this.loadframe = loadframe;
        writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(Project.getInstance().getFileURLStr() + Project.getInstance().getProjectName() + ".mp4");
        dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4, dimension.width / 2, dimension.height / 2);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Project project = Project.getInstance();
        for (int index = 0; index <= project.getTimeLineImageCount(); index++) {
            loadframe.updateProgress(index/project.getTimeLineImageCount());
            ImageIcon imgtoencode = (ImageIcon)project.getNextTimeLineImage();
            BufferedImage imgtoencodebuf = (BufferedImage)imgtoencode.getImage();
            writer.encodeVideo(0, imgtoencodebuf, System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        }
        project.setWalkIndexes();
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

Wich should be converting a list of images to a video. But when I try to run it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.<init>(JNIMemoryManager.java:861)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.<clinit>(JNIMemoryManager.java:860)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.<clinit>(MediaWriter.java:119)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeWriter(ToolFactory.java:149)
    at Operations.ImageToVideo.<init>(ImageToVideo.java:31)
    at GUI.MainScreen.actionPerformed(MainScreen.java:501)
```

etc. I got the code from an example on internet:http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/xuggler/create-video-from-image-frames-with-xuggler/"

I am really new to Xuggle, I hope someone can help me out here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `sl4j` library  *Xuggle will not work without that*

Download library from here `-->` http://www.slf4j.org/download.html and add the jar's to your project library (*class path*)

Comment: Thanks! I indeed did miss it :)